# Is it OK to propose to present research in a conference as a grad student?

Tags: graduate-school, conference, physics

I am a first year grad student, studying abroad, and there is a conference in the country where I am from which I think can be a good experience (I have never presented in a serious conference) to present the  research being carried in my group. Is it OK for me as a student to propose my supervisor to present our research there?

A bit of context: there are like 8-9 people in my group, I thought of attending the congress as I would probably be in vacation anyway there, so my group would not have to cover the travelling expenses. The only thing is that I dont think that anyone from my group would travel with me, as my country is like 20 hours away from where I'm pursuing my grad studies.

Comment: Buffy's advice is good, but I think it's worth asking: Are you considering submitting written work to a conferences whose proceedings are officially published, or thinking about giving an "unpublished" oral presentation?

Comment: Unpublished oral presentation. But my question was more inclined towards if it's okay to ask my supervisor 'permission' to present? I am new in the group and I don't know if it's a good option to seek for conferences or if I should expect my supervisor to tell me

Comment: The answer is simple. Discuss this with your supervisor.

Comment: I mean ask him without looking pretentious. "Would it be a good idea if...."

Comment: Yes of course! I would love to go, but I wanted to know whether asking could be seen as 'pretentious' or something. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the best conference presentations I've seen are from first year grad students. I think it's great to get a feel for the process as early as possible and should speak to your advisor, who would probably be a co-author on the abstract submission. Even if you don't get selected to speak, it's good practice for learning how to apply to speak at conferences.

Comment: Thank you for the advice! :D

Answer (score 5):

Yes it is fine to submit to a conference as a student. But it is up to the committee whether your paper/proposal is accepted. Some conferences have special sessions for student work, actually.

It is also fine to seek advice from your advisor on this. In particular, you might get good advice about whether your work is actually ready for presentation.  But, in general, don't hesitate to ask.

Make sure you give proper credit to the others in your group.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But my question was more inclined towards if it's okay to ask my supervisor 'permission' to present? I am new in the group and I don't know if it's a good option to seek for conferences or if I should expect my supervisor to tell me @Buffy

Comment: Thanks for the advice!